# How to override SQL Server default value constraint on a boolean when inserting new entity?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, boolean, default-constraint

This project is using Entity Framework code-first.

I have an entity called `Department` with a boolean value that specifies whether it is an active department. Here is a simplified version of the entity definition. There are also no fluent mappings for the `Active` property.

```
public class Department
{
    public Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

In the database the column for `Active` is a `bit, not null`.

We have a default constraint in the database for the `Active` column to set newly created entries to true.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Active]
```

The problem is that when I create a new entity the user can choose to set `Active` as false, but this property is false when it is added to the context, but after save changes is called, the property is true and it is true in the database record.

```
Guid ICommonRepository.AddDepartment(Department newDepartment)
{
    using(var db = new CommonDbContext())
    {
        if(newDepartment.DepartmentId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            newDepartment.DepartmentId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        db.Departments.Add(newDepartment); // Here newDepartment.Active is false
        db.SaveChanges();
        return newDepartment.DepartmentId; // Here newDepartment.Active is true
    }
}
```

Is there a setting in EF or an annotation that I can use on the `Active` column that will allow me to specify false?

Comment: Are you 100% sure there are no annotations or fluent mappings on the property? I was under the impression that sql default values only apply themselves to the model if you have `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` on the property.

Comment: You say "*but this property is false when it is added to the context, but after save changes is called, the property is false and it is false in the database record.*", did you mean to say  "*but this property is false when it is added to the context, but after save changes is called, the property is **true** and it is **true** in the database record.*", that is what your code example below is saying is happening. It is not clear to me which problem you are having. Are you ***currently*** getting `newDepartment.Active == true` after you do `db.SaveChanges()` or is that what you wanting to get?

Comment: `Default constraint` is applied only when column is not provided via `insert` at all.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That was a typo, it is true in the SQL record and in the entity after save changes. Also I did forget to mention that there is a '[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]' annotation on 'Active' but there are no fluent mappings. I've updated the question to reflect those changes.

Comment: @IvanStarostin That's what I though, and that's what my experimentation showed me when testing some SQL 'insert' statements. I could insert it as false, but if I didn't provide an 'Active' value it then it was set to true.

Comment: There's your problem. With `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` set, EF will not try to set the value and therefore take the default. Unset this annotation.

Comment: @ChrisPickford Thanks, that fixed it. Add it as an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` from the `Active` field of your Model.

Entity Framework will not try to persist a value to the database which is why the default is being set.

Comment: Is there a better way to apply a default constraint in EF that will also allow me to set false values explicitly?

Comment: Yes, in EF7 using Fluent API: http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/relational/default-values.html

Comment: Fluent doesn't seem to support HasDefaultValue for booleans. If I try `modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().Property(m => m.Active).HasDefaultValue(true);` it doesn't recognize HasDefaultValue.

Comment: Are you using entity framework 7?

Comment: We are using EF 6.1.3